# When to use an Enum vs Struct

Tags: c#

In our database we have a table called ObjectType. This table simply contains a series of rows with an Id and and ObjectName. In our back-end code, we handle different objects in different ways, so it's often required to refer to the ID of an object for comparisons. These IDs are always the same, and they always map to the same object.

What construct would be better for handling these objects if my methods are expecting an integer value to be passed to them?

When would I use a struct? When would I use an enum?

Comment: The first that came to my mind was  a class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Enumerations aren't interchangable with structs. They have completely different usages. A struct can have members and methods, but an enumeration can have only labels and values for the labels.

You could use an enum to specify different behaviours of a system

Let's say you have a class Person and let's say that for whatsoever reason a person can have an emotional state.

A good implementation would use an enum like this:

```
enum EmotionalState
{
     Happy = 3,
     Sad,
     Shy    
}
```

You can use the enum items as integers like this :

```
int b = (int)EmotionalState.Sad // <---4
```

and also in the reverse direction

```
int v = 3;
EmotionalState s = (EmotionalState)v; // Happy
```

Note that the enum members don't have type. They could also be assigned a starting value. So for example if you assign 3 on the first item the next item would be marked as 4.

A good example for a struct is a Point

```
struct Point {
   int a;
   int b;
}
```

structs should be small as they are value types and are kept on the stack where as reference types are kept on the heap.

Comment: The only real need I have is to be able to see Id/Value is stored within each object. That way if I say `var someVar = ObjectType.Role`, I would be able to assign an integer value to `someVar`. It would also make my code more readable as I wouldn't be saying `if (objectType == 15) { }`. I just need to make sure that the value assigned to the variable remains easily accessible as I use the numeric Id in multiple insertions/queries. In the past, I've used structs with statically defined values or consts.

Comment: @Jdsfighter you could relate them in a single enum if that makes conceptual sense ( such as the example with the emotional state ). 
The value that you assigned at the enum is easily accessible e.g EmotionalState b = (EmotionalState)15;

Comment: "an enumeration can have only labels and values for the labels." This is wrong, an enum can also include other members.

Answer (score 4):

`struct` is not an alternative to `enum`, it's an alternative to a `class`. It is just the memory layout which is different in a struct and in a class.

If you don't need to have your code follow and support new entries added to your DB, I would go for enums.

Otherwise, if you need to support new DB entires, I would consider a `Dictionary<int, string>`

Comment: Essentially, what I'm looking to do is be able to use the integer value contained within the object to determine what object is selected, and then use the Id to manipulate other records. For example saying `ObjectType.User` would return 9, so in my code I can assign this value to another record/variable, but I could also use it for comparisons. These values wouldn't need to be fetched from the database as there is pretty much no chance they'll ever change.

Comment: Enum definitely then. Downside : you need to keep them in sync with the DB

Answer (score 1):

enum is a list of different options that can be selected, a struct is used for storing variables (yes it is something like a class, but mostly used for just storing data)

```
enum Sports {
        Soccer, Tennis, Football, Baseball
}
```

would output: `Sports.
                     | Soccer     |
                     | Tennis     |
                     | Footbal    |
                     | Baseball   |`

Comment: In my case, I'm simply wanting to store an integer value within each variable/option. This way I can easily extract the value and perform queries if necessary, but it also prevents me from using magic numbers in my comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the entire `ObjectType` table into a `Dictionary<string, int>`. Map the `id` with `ObjectName`. For the methods which are expecting the int, you can pass them `objectTypeMapping["objectName"]`.

Comment: Fortunately the `ObjectType` table is fairly small, and completely static. Once defined in code, I'd simply like to be able to call something like `ObjectType.User` and I would have an integer value returned.

Comment: @Jdsfighter: Both enum and Dictionary are ok for that case. Are you, even if the ObjectType table is static, guaranteed to have your ids in increments of 1 always? If not, go with Dictionary because it is easier to  let the application prepare the dictionary automatically every time at startup after reading the table, rather than modifying the hard-coded enum manually when your table has changed.

Comment: The table data is and always will be static. In the past, the developers have hard coded the IDs into every line of code. There are hundreds (if not thousands) of stored procedures that refer to the objects by their ID only. And in our backend code, it's more of the same.

Comment: @Jdsfighter: Ok, so you are trying to improve the readability of your code by refactoring out the hard-coded ids. You are looking for enums only then. Prepare your enum class and then search your solution for all magic numbers that are supposed to be replaced with `ObjectType.User` kind of lines.